# Divided Difference Table

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

In the context of a problem I am working on, it would be useful to have examples of polynomials with certain features. I know given $n$ points, you can use a divided difference table to find a polynomial of degree $n+1$ going through these points. This is easy. However, I have heard you can also find polynomials with specified derivative values.

Can anyone explain how to use the divided difference table to find a polynomial with $p(0)=1$, $p(3)=1$, and $p'(2)=0$? Or something like $p(0)=1$, $p'(2)=3$, and $p''(3)=-1$? Even links to resources explaining this process would be helpful. I have not found any searching for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for osculating polynomials.

Here are some links that include nice notes and examples:

- http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~iron/math2400/osculating.pdf
- http://www.math.uconn.edu/~olshevsky/classes/2015_Spring/math3511/Interpolation.pdf
- http://web.mnstate.edu/jamesju/Fall2014/Content/M450HermiteInterp.pdf

Burden and Faires has a nice section on Hermite Polynomials as well as many other texts on Numerical Analysis / Algorithms.